# Using string as variable in function (Python)

Tags: python, string, function, variables

I have trouble to find out a solution here.

Basically, I have an URL backbone where I would like to change one part  (different words) automatically according to an excel sheet (having one column of single strings).
you would have for instance: URL1=https://XXXWORD1XXX, URL2=https://XXXWORD2XXX, etc

so the first code works but what if I would like to give a list of query through an excel sheet?

```
def function(query):
    url = "https//:XXXXX" + query + "XXXXX"

    blablabla

    return blablabla


print(function("Biotech"))
```

```
def function(query):
    url1 = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=AREA%%5D+" + query + "++AND+AREA%5BOverallStaPAND%5BTerm%5D+"
    response1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url1).read()
    ***Exception has occurred: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type'***

    blablabla

    return blablabla

# select excel file
path = easygui.fileopenbox("Select excel file with column named query")
xls = pd.read_excel(path)
directory_path = path[:-5]
df_query = pd.DataFrame(xls)

queries = pd.DataFrame(df_query, columns= ['query']) 

for index, row in queries.iterrows():
    print(row)
    print(clinicalgov(row))
    print()
```

thanks for any suggestions! best

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a list of strings as parameter to the function and return the list of the processed answers for each string.

for code 1: query will be a list, for loop inside function and returning blablabla is also list.

Comment: ah thanks! but then you would perform a loop inside the function to treat the entire list?

Comment: yes just perform all the operations on each element of list and store the answers to a new list. you can get both query and blablabla lists as return values.

Comment: but lets say i want to treat it one by one. how to I enter a variable as string in the function? Right now, function(row) does not work.

Comment: can you give the example or paste code that you have written so i can undertand your problem.

Comment: hello, ive updated the second code of what i am exactly trying to do. thanks for your help! (error message intervenes @ response1

Comment: instead of passing dataframe, make a linewise split list, 
with open(file,'r')as f: 
data = f.read().split("\n") 
then pass the list to your function 
this is easy and fast approach. why do you want to use heavy weight dataframes.!